# make memory efficient two python list combination

Tags: python

I have two lists and need to run about all combinations of two lists.

usually below code is works well.

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list_b = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
all_combinations = [(x,y) for x in list_a for y in list_b] # <- this line is not beautiful.
results = [Func(x) for x in all_combinations ]
```

Line 3 is the problem. it is waste of memory.

I checked every functions in "itertools" , but cannot find anything good for me.

How can make Line 3 as generator, memory efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is built the Cartesian product A x B.
You can use the `itertools.product` iterator which is equivalent to `((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`.

```
results = [Func(x) for x in product(list_a, list_b) ]
```

---

As noted below, this creates a second copy of the inputs lists and creates a memory overhead in the size of len(A)+len(B).

Yet timewise is product much faster in the following experiment:

```
A = list(range(100000))
B = list(range(10000))

>>> timeit( lambda : [x for x in product(A,B)], number=10000)
4.071

# Note here only 1000 instead of 10000
>>> timeit( lambda : [x for x in ((a,b) for a in A for b in B)], number=1000)
7.226
```

Probably because it does use better C implementations underneath for and has not need to work on the standard lists A, B.
In practice (for one iteration) this has no significant impact.

Comment: Just a note *"Before product() runs, it completely consumes the input iterables, keeping pools of values in memory to generate the products. Accordingly, it is only useful with finite inputs."*, not sure if OP thought of this kind of memory optimization (but it's not quadratic). In any case, the intermediate list is useless as you showed ;)

Comment: Good to know. Do you know if that counts for lists as well? It does make sense to consume generators, lists could theoretically be used as is.

Comment: @Daraan Yes, it applies to lists as well. You can test this by modifying one of the lists before consuming the product.

Comment: `product` has to store the inputs to lists, since it would have to iterate at least one iterable many times over which is often not possible.

Comment: @user2390182  I think what Daraan meant is that the implementation of product could, in theory, type check whether the input(s) were lists and not duplicate them in memory in that case, but just hold a reference on them.

Comment: I added a speed check of these two methods. product is much faster but that probably has not much relevance and comes at the expense of the overhead memory you mentioned.

Comment: It's faster because it has a C implementation, not Python. I'm unsure why you're talking about linked lists here, nothing in the answer is using linked lists.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for an intermediate step at all in this case:

```
results = [Func((x,y)) for x in list_a for y in list_b]
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of time complexity, you can't do better than `O(m*n)`. You can save space by using a generator:

```
((x, y) for x in A for y in B)
```

This is equivalent to `itertools.product`

```
product(A, B)
```

Now to apply a function to all those pairs, use `map`:

```
map(Func, product(A, B))
```

This is lazy, however, and needs to be consumed:

```
for result in map(Func, product(A, B)):
    # do stuff with result
```

If you are just interested in the side effects of `Func`, not the results, you can use the itertools `consume` recipe using `collections.deque`:

```
consume = lambda it: deque(it, maxlen=0)

consume(map(Func, product(A, B)))
# for _ in map(Func, product(A, B)): pass
```

Comment: Probably the best approach, since memory usage is definitely an issue according to OP.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, just change the square brackets to parentheses.

List comprehension:

```
all_combinations = [(x,y) for x in list_a for y in list_b]
```

Generator expression:

```
all_combinations = ((x,y) for x in list_a for y in list_b)
```

The relevant itertools function would be using [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), although it is not an exact equivalent. The generator expression will follow mutations in the input lists, but the product won't since it consumes all inputs entirely at initialization. The generator expression will be slower but more memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

itertools.product() function should give you the result you are looking for:

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list_b = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

import itertools

all_combinations = [itertools.product(list_a, list_b)]
results = [Func(x) for x in all_combinations ]
```